# How can I parallelize a function with multiple arguments

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have written a function `create_time_series(input_df1, info_df1, unit_name,start_date,end_date)`, which aims to create a time series based on log-files saved in `input_df1`.
The problem of my function is that the execution is slow, therefore I thought of parallelizing it.

The following code is my attempt at utilizing the multiprocessing library:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
arg = corrected_data,block_info,(unit for unit in block_info.UnitID.unique()),"2015-01-01","2021-12-31"
with Pool(processes = 16) as pool:
    temp_data = pool.starmap(create_time_series,arg)
    out_data = pd.concat([out_data,temp_data[unit]],axis =1)
```

In the task manager, I can see the processes running however, those seem to be idling. Hence my question, what did I do wrong in attempting to parallelize the task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not splitting your load, and giving the process pool only one item to process (`arg`). Check the documentation for [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap): it expects an iterable (e.g. list) of tuples, each of which has all the required arguments

Comment: First of all, thanks for the response. I thought the arg would be passed as an iterable, because of the `(unit for unit in block_info.UnitID.unique())` part, as you said it is not. How can I pass the parameters onto the process pool for `unit` while keeping the other parameters constant ?

Comment: @Guilly if that's what you want you can do `[(corrected_data, block_info, unit, "2015-01-01", "2021-12-31") for unit in block_info.UnitID.unique()]`

Comment: I assume, that I should replace this `arg` term with the `[(corrected_data, block_info, unit, "2015-01-01", "2021-12-31") for unit in block_info.UnitID.unique()]`. Since the new term contains an explicit iterable. 
To be fair, I am rather confused, this is specifically what arg contains.

Comment: @Guilly no it is not. As you wrote it, arg is something like `(corrected_data, block_info, (unit_1,unit_2,unit_3), "2015-01-01", "2021-12-31")`. The other comprehension that I showed you will create something like this: `[(corrected_data,block_info,unit1,"2015-01-01", "2021-12-31"),(corrected_data,block_info,unit_2,"2015-01-01", "2021-12-31"),(corrected_data,block_info,unit_3,"2015-01-01", "2021-12-31")]`